# Find the vector of medians from the occurrences of the negative values of the vector in matlab

Tags: matlab

Say I have a vector

```
v =[1,2,3,-1,-2,-3,4,5,6,-7,-6,-3,-5,-4,...]
```

I want to make a vector which consists of the values of the occurrence of negative values.

When the pointer is at `v[4]` till the last negative value `v[6]`

Next step I need to take the median from the vector v of the first occurrences of the negative values

```
Vm = [-2] % first occurrence
```

Accordingly I want to repeat the procedure for `v[10]` till `v[13]` and determine the median again.

And add it up to the vector `Vm = [-2,-3]` and so on. The output should be like this: `vm = [(median(v(4) to v(6)), (median(v(10) to v(13))),...]`

So for this example the vector should look like this `vm = [-2,-4,...]`

Comment: Isn't your example self-contradictory? First you've stated that the output should be `Vm=[-2, -3]` then you said it to be `[-2,-4]` for the given `v`. Why are you taking the median of `v(10) to v(13)`? Why not `v(10) to v(14)`? `v(14)` is also a negative value. Why isn't it taken? As it see it, it should be `median of v(10) to v(14)` which is `-5`. So the output should be `[-2,-5]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
v =[1,2,3,-1,-2,-3,4,5,6,-7,-6,-3,-5,-4]; %Given vector
%Start and end of intervals. strfind is applicable on numeric data as well.
pos = [1,v>=0,1];    start = strfind(pos,[1,0]);     last = strfind(pos,[0,1])-1;

n=length(start); %Number of chunks of the negative values
vm = zeros(1,n); %Pre-allocation of vm
for k=1:n
    vm(k) = median(v(start(k):last(k)));  %Finding required vector of medians   
end
```

If there is no negative value, `vm` will be returned as an empty vector.

---

<sup>Regarding the statement, "*I want to make a vector which consists of the values of the occurrence of negative values.*", it seems that it is not your actual goal but you can find that with `v(v<0)`.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

One possibility using logical indexing with a for-loop would be

```
v =[1,2,3,-1,-2,-3,4,5,6,-7,-6,-3,-5,-4];
% find negative values
flg_negative=v<0;
%get start of interval
idx_start=find(diff(flg_negative)==1)+1;
%get end of interval
idx_end=find(diff(flg_negative)==-1);
%sanity check for beginning (if v(1) is negativ)
if idx_start(1)>idx_end(1)
    idx_start=[1 idx_start];
end
%if vector ends with a negative value adjust
if idx_start(end)>idx_end(end)
    idx_end=[idx_end length(v)];
end
%number of intervals
n=length(idx_start);
%alloc output
vm=zeros(n,1);
%loop over intervals
for kk=1:n
    %calc median
    vm(kk)=median(v(idx_start(kk):idx_end(kk)));
end
```

you should check if flg_negative is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is using `for`:

```
 flag = 0;
 negs = [];
 medians = [];
 for idx = 1:length(v)
      % add to negs up to finding next positive
      if(v(idx) < 0)
          negs = [negs v(idx)];
          flag = 1; 
      % find median of founded negs and reset the negs and flag
      elseif(v(idx) > 0 && flag== 1)
           medians = [medians median(negs)];
           negs = [];
           flag = 0;
      end
 end
```