# Select several ranges of a column according to their value and insert the mean value of the second column into a new matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, mean

I have a matrix:

V1  V2
1   12
1   12
0   23
0   24
1   45
1   67

I want to calculate the mean of the successive values of V2 only as long as V1 is >0 and insert the results into a new matrix. I want to do this for all values of V1. In this example I would get:

12
56

Any idea how I can do this in Matlab? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the vector of medians from the occurrences of the negative values of the vector in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45692193/find-the-vector-of-medians-from-the-occurrences-of-the-negative-values-of-the-ve)

Comment: There will be many ways to solve your problem, however the question is: what have you tried and where do you fail? In the link above you find a very similar question. Your problem is easier as you already have an boolean Vector V1 telling you which values to average  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using [`cumsum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) and [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
V1 = V1 > 0;
f = find(V1,1);
subs = cumsum(diff([false;V1]) == 1);
p = V1 .* V2;
result = accumarray (                ...
            subs(f:end),             ...
            f:numel(V1),             ...
            [],                      ...
            @(x)sum(p(x))./sum(V1(x))...
        );
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the idea of manipulating `V1` and creating `subs` from [rahnema1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6579744/rahnema1)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50875350/), here is an alternative way of using [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
V1 = V1 > 0;
subs = cumsum(diff([false;V1]) == 1);
result = accumarray (subs(V1), V2(V1), [], @mean);
```

---

**Benchmark:**
Here is a comparison of the two answers:

```
V1 = repmat(V1,1e6,1);   
V2 = repmat(V2,1e6,1);    
V1 = V1 > 0;
subs = cumsum(diff([false;V1]) == 1);

disp(['rahnema1''s answer = ', num2str(timeit(@() rahnema1(V1,V2,subs)))]);
disp(['Usama''s answer = ', num2str(timeit(@() usama(V1,V2,subs)))]);

function rahnema1(V1,V2,subs)
p = V1 .* V2;
f = find(V1,1);
result = accumarray (subs(f:end), f:numel(V1), [], @(x)sum(p(x))./sum(V1(x)));
end

function usama(V1,V2,subs)
result = accumarray (subs(V1),V2(V1), [], @mean);
end
```

```
rahnema1's answer = 4.3385
Usama's answer = 5.6088
```

⇒ [rahnema1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6579744/rahnema1)'s code is faster than that of mine.